# what is difference between addListenerForSingleValueEvent and addChildEventListener methods of Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was working of firebase database query. But it was little confusing while reading docs as they write there `addChildEventListener()` listener's `onChildAdded()` will call every time a child added.

My scenario is that I want to query all children. Should it done with above method or with `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`?

As also they mention in doc that listener should detach like `ref.removeEventListener(originalListener)`

1. what does it mean?
2. is it going to call again and again when new data added in db?

Comment: Instead of asking here to clarify the documentation, I highly recommend that you try it. Create a snippet for each (`addChildEventListener()` and `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()`), then add a few items to you database and see what happens. Without doing that, we'll just be rehashing the documentation for you. If the behavior you get still doesn't make sense, post your code snippet and what you expected it to do.

Comment: Thank you for valuable advice.. i will definitely use both methods for comparison soon, as of now i was using addListenerForSingleValueEvent(), that is understand little more than addChildEventListener(). Thank you again. will update my question soon. :)

Answer (score 4):

both of them are the same, it depends on how you gonna use it. Personally i think *ChildEventListener* is more flexible to use, because you can define what to do regarding the action happened (such as when a child is added, changed, or removed). based on the [documentations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data), the only difference is *ValueEventListener* will do the 'things' you defined regarding the change happened (be it added, changed, or removed) because it only has one listener `OnDataChange()`. Meanwhile *ChildEventListener* has 4 listener, `onChildAdded()`, `onChildChanged()`, `onChildRemoved()`, and `onChildMoved()` so you can defines what to do within each listener/action.

As for `removeEventListener()`, it is necessary because firebase is reactive, and firebase actively listen to what happens at the given node(database reference). So when you remove the listener, it won't be listening to the given node therefore any changes made after `removeEventListener()` won't be recognized by firebase. And yes both *ChildEventListener* and *ValueEventListener* will always listen actively and do the defined actions everytime new data added (`onDataChange()` and `onChildAdded()`.

CMIIW and pardon my english.
Regards,

RM